# jQuery resizable - change value of parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to change `maxWidth` and `minWidth`dynamically.
These two values are calculated when the document is ready and when the window is resized.

For example the variable for `maxWidth` is equal to `80% - 12px`. That calculation works fine.

The problem is that `resizable` doesn't update it's options - it uses the value of maxWidth which was set in the beginning.

How do I update the options (new maxWidth) of `resizable`?

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hausmaster/jmh82eag/3/)

Thanks a lot! :)

EDIT: Because I was asked to post some code here as well:

```
var maxWidth = 300;
var minWidth = 50;

function calc() {
    var maxWidth = ($( "#resize" ).parent().width()*0.8)-12;
    var minWidth = ($( "#resize" ).parent().width()*0.2)-12;
  $("p").text(maxWidth + " - " + minWidth);
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
  calc();
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  calc();
})

$(function() {
  $("#resize").resizable({
    maxHeight: 150,
    maxWidth: maxWidth,
    minHeight: 150,
    minWidth: minWidth,
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
    grid: [10, 10],
  });
});
```

Comment: Post some code here too

Comment: @OlegMeleshko - I can't see changes nor does it work /:

Comment: i've modified calc function (removed `var`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `calc()` function

```
function calc() {
    var maxWidth = ($( "#resize" ).parent().width()*0.8)-12;
    var minWidth = ($( "#resize" ).parent().width()*0.2)-12;
    $("p").text(maxWidth + " - " + minWidth);
    $("#resize").resizable('option', 'maxWidth', maxWidth);
    $("#resize").resizable('option', 'minWidth', minWidth);  
}
```

See docs here: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#method-option

Comment: Thanks - that works for me! But only if I don't call `calc()` on ready - why is that? https://jsfiddle.net/hausmaster/jmh82eag/5/

Comment: Hey, in fact you could just add the options updating code to the resize listener instead of calc function - that should do the job.
You can update the options only if the resizable was first initiated, and in your case it's initiating at the very last ready listener. In case you didn't know `$(function)` is just a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function)`